# Is it possible to see the assembly of an entire library and place a breakpoint?

Tags: xcode

I am finding it difficult to debug disassembled C/C++ since I can only place breakpoints within an encountered call stack. I'm currently having to break and just hope that I get lucky, but usually I'm just stuck with threads that are spinning idly.

I'm able to do this when attached with Hopper Disassembler, but its debugger UI is not very helpful since I can't look at locals. I assume I might be able to add a breakpoint at a specific address based on Hopper's full disassembly, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a symbolic breakpoint in the Breakpoint Navigator if you know the name of a function where you'd like to start debugging.

If this is a library that you've built, there are instructions here for picking up symbols: http://lldb.llvm.org/symbols.html